# Midori stopped displaying tabs bar on Lubuntu 16.04.1 and 14.04.4

Tags: lubuntu, tabs, midori

I installed midori on Lubuntu 14.04.4 32 bit because it's relatively faster than other browsers and it stopped displaying the tabs bar soon after installing it. I have two accounts and the problem happened on both but not at the same time, and it hasn't been fixed after upgrading to Lubuntu 16.04.1.

I can go to "settings" and select "tabs pannel" to see the tabs I've got at the moment, but it's quite a big pannel and there's no easy way to manage it.

How can I get the tabs bar visible and working again? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really solve the Midori issue, but I believe Midori is not being developed anymore.

I personally recommend you switch to Epiphany browser (Gnome Web), it is very light and more stable than Midori.

> sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I recommend [Brave](http://brave.com/). Give it a try!

Comment: It does actually. I thought Midori was updated and using an out of date browser is a risk. I'll give it a try, since my computer might be as limited as a Raspberry pi. Thanks.